# Convert pdf to html/xml using c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-to-html

I want to **convert pdf to html** using c#...
Can anyone please give any ideas..

Comment: Over 2500 results when searching google only within SO...

Comment: @Abel: I think that question asks for HTML to PDF.

Comment: @Greg: yes, I think so too and that's the reverse, my bad. I updated my answer, and will remove the dup comment, which isn't a dup :S

Comment: PS: related, but not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277901/in-asp-net-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-html/277971

Answer (score 0):

Edit (original contained link to html to pdf, not the other way around):

[With Google, I got you this](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-convert-pdf-file-to-text-in.html), which is close (generates text). It should give you a starting point. In [this thread on asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/1417395/3130077.aspx), it explained how you can get HTML using that technique (skip to the code example).

And, on SO, have a search for this [pdf-to-html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-to-html), and you'll [find this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277901/in-asp-net-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-html/277971). Check out the link for [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/), which'll give you an interface to the PDF document.

Comment: This answer is HTML to PDF.  The original question is for the other way round.

Comment: @Richard: i just edited when you typed your comment, refresh, it's now the other way around :)